# OpenXava "Ha sido imposible ejecutar la acción Init list: Transacción marcada para ser cancelada únicamente"

Tags: java, openxava

Me muestra ese error al tratar de grabar algún elemento a la lista, en la documentación no lo menciona. No estoy haciendo uso de MySQL, agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Adjunto código[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y capturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Sería necesario la traza de error para saber la causa exacta, sin embargo ya veo dos cosas en el código que pueden ser las causantes. La primera es que las propiedades han de empezar con minúscula, es la nomenclatura estándar de Java. La segunda es que la longitud de 32 está reservada para las claves, si las usas para algo que no es clave puede dar problemas, y esto es un peculiaridad de OpenXava.

Es decir, cambia:

```
@Column(length=32,nullable=true,name="si")
String Description;
```

Por:

```
@Column(length=40,nullable=true,name="si")
String description;
```

Recurda que name es el nombre de la columna, en tu case la columna para guardar "descripcion" en la tabla se llamará "si".